# function parameter as a part of variable name

Tags: php, function

I was wondering if I can pass function argument as a part of variables name and create new one. Like example below

```
function do_anything($name) {
    global ${$name}_anything;
    ${$name}_anything = 'hello_world';
}

do_anything('unique');
echo $unique_anything;
```

Comment: For gods sake what are you trying ?

Comment: I want to insert some repeatable data into sql which differs only with some part of url query and names ofc and gets diffrent values that api returns ofc.

Comment: Understood, so why exactly do you need globals + variable variables then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't tell anyone I wrote this.

```
<?php

function do_anything($name) {
    global ${$name . "_anything"};
    ${$name . "_anything"} = 'hello_world';

}
do_anything('unique');
echo $unique_anything;
```

Comment: works lol,. thank you. Why don't you want me to tell You wrote this? Is it bad practise or something?

Comment: @artofbw I don't really understand why you need to work with global and dynamic variables names. Imagine one day, someone have to debug your code, he'll search for $unique_anything and will never find where you defined it. Maybe you should try to find another way of doing what you want, with arrays maybe.

Comment: Yeah. I tried arrays at first. It's kinda weather script. I need to insert multiple cities and temperatures into one row, that's why I couldn't do it with foreach loop. At least I think so, and that's why I decide for a dynami variables (I thought this is a good idea, but see bad part of solution ofc). Maybe you have any tips?

My only better, but not really impressive solution was to separate all api's link for a request (make ton of variables)

Comment: Sadly my english is not good enough to fully understand what you want to do and to provide you a good answer. Maybe we should continue this discussion in the chat ?

Comment: I'm ok. Thanks for your help anyway :)